# Static library built-in rule in GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu

I'm a newbie in GNU make and I'm reading "Managing Projects with GNU make - O'Reilly" book.

In Chapter 2, Building library section, the book introduced 2 ways for updating an archive library (static - .a).

The first one:

```
libname.a: preq1.o preq2.o
                     $(AR) $(ARFLGS) $@ $?
```

The second one:

```
libname.a(preq1.o): preq1.o
                     $(AR) $(ARFLGS) $@ $<
```

How does libname.a(preq1.o) increase performance of updating a static library?

Also I guess that the second format may be overhead if the library has a lot of members (hundreds or thousands), is this right?

Is this the following built-in rule?

```
(%): %
#  commands to execute (built-in):
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the first example, the entire archive file is recreated from scratch every time.  In the second example, the archive is preserved and only the single object file `preq1.o` is replaced with a new copy.  In any archive you're likely to find and with any system available today it's unlikely you'll be able to tell the difference unless your archive has hundreds or more objects in it.  When make was written, things were a lot slower and these types of efficiency enhancements made a big difference.

Comment: @MadScientist : you should submit this as an answer

Comment: @MadScientist First thanks for your reply, but I've a comment the first example the archive will only update the out-dated files because I pass "$?" to "$(AR)".
So, I think both are updating only the out-dated members, but the book said the second one is the best?

Comment: Yes, that's true, I didn't notice that.  Well, then I have no explanation for that comment in that book.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be able to provide you with a slightly fuller answer based on my - also limited - knowledge of the GNU Make utility. The first form of the recipe merely specifies that 'libname.a' depends on the following list of object files. If any of those files are younger than the last-updated time of 'libname.a' - then 'libname.a' will, as MadScientist says, be recreated in its entirety from scratch. In this sense, 'libname.a' is no different from any other Make target. In the second form, the dependency itself is NOT 'libname.a' but the insertion timestamps of the subordinate object files within the archive. Here, 'libname.a' is not actually tested at all. The insertion timestamp of each object file is tested within the archive and any DEPENDENT files whose last-modified date is younger than the corresponding object member file then cause the object file to be rebuilt, the archive to be updated with the rebuilt object file AND the object file then to be deleted - which I personally think is brilliant. There are 2 caveats; The first is that 'libname.a' must already exist (even if it's just an empty file) before the make recipe will work UNLESS you specify the '-c' flag invoking make to force the initial creation of the archive. The second refers to thread safety. Rebuilding the entire archive member by member may result in several recipes being run in parallel. In this case, there is a high likelihood of the target archive being corrupted (due to the perennial problem associated with multiple file handles on the archive) unless the 'noparallel' directive is specified at the top of the makefile. To answer the thrust of your question, the second form is more efficient simply because only outdated archive component modules are rebuilt and re-inserted instead of the entire archive being rebuilt from the top down. Hope this helps - V.V.